# perform segue on application enter foreground with multiple views?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, segue

I would like to move back to my main view using a segue. When the home button is pressed and the app enters the background.... then later the user wishes to open the application again bringing it to the foreground I would like a segue to be run which takes them from whatever view they were in back to the 'main view'. I dont mind using multiple segues... or how could I access these segues in the app delegate for example.

What is the best method for this? Thankyou! beer and points for everyone who gives a good answer ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may implement the `applicationWillEnterForeground:application:` method (from the UIApplicationDelegate protocol). This method is called whenever your application's state changes from backgo to inactive state (before it goes to active).

In this method you could call `performSegueWithIdentifier:identifier sender:`. If you have a segue from each possible view back to your main view, your are done.

However, unless your application has a very complex state that would need lots of time to reconstruct, I would recommend to do general a re-initialization of your application in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or `applicationDidBecomeActive:`. In this way it is easier to preserve a consistent state.

Comment: shouldn't it be better to do an "unwind" instead of a new segue?